# SVG javascript animation is janky on firefox but smooth on chrome

Tags: javascript, performance, svg

I have a simple wireframe renderer, outputting with svg. An example of use is on the site:

https://0polymer0.github.io/implementation/Teapot/Teapot.html

Polygon elements, representing triangles, are updated in an animation loop.

The svg renderer works well on Chrome, but not on Firefox. Can this be fixed? And if not, why?

I think the performance relevant code is here:

```
for(let i = 0; i < mesh.length; i++){
    dom_mesh[i].setAttributeNS(null, 
        "points", 
        triangle2D_to_string(screenspace_mesh[i])
    );
}
```

**Things I've tried**

Converting `childElements()` output to an array (`dom_mesh`) didn't change anything. Reading from children didn't change anything. And directly accessing attributes rather than assigning strings to "points" didn't change anything.

I think the problem has to do with writing to svg, because the benchmarks suggest that's where the browser is spending most of its time.

I'm open to this approach being unworkable, I'm just surprised it is working as well as it is on chrome. It would be nice to understand why.

Comment: Seems OK to me on a Mac. It would be faster if a) you used the SVG DOM to manipulate the points rather than setAttributeNS or b) if you used a 3d CSS transform then you don't need to change the points at all.

Comment: I used the interface specified by: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransformList. I did `getItem().point.x` etc. And that didn't seem to improve performance.

What do you have in mind for 3D CSS transforms? I haven't used them before. 

The idea of the project is to learn rendering algorithms. Can I attach the SVG's to points using CSS?

Comment: I mean't [this interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html#InterfaceSVGAnimatedPoints) which avoids serialisation. And CSS 3d transforms are described on [MDN too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d)

Comment: Thank you for the references, I'll play with them!